# Styling a button with hover effect

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues with my code.

I added this button to my HTML page and CSS with the styling of the button class and the hover effect:

```css
.buton4e {
  background-color: #383f95;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.buton4e:hover {
  background-color: #383f95;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.intro-header {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  background: url(../img/background.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.intro-message {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}

.intro-message>h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 5em;
}

.intro-divider {
  width: 400px;
  border-top: 1px solid #f8f8f8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.intro-message>h3 {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
<header class="intro-header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="intro-message">
      <br /><br /><br />
      <h3>90% of IT companies believe they need to partner to grow.<br /> Join <b>Channeliser</b> - the global network for building IT partnerships.</h3>
      <hr class="intro-divider">
      <a href="#content-section-a"><button class="buton4e">JOIN FOR FREE</button></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

The problem is that the effect works when I hover the button but there when the button is static it has no styling

*EDIT:

Sorry for not posting all the code.

This should be sufficient for the things I'm trying to modify.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have created a Fiddle for this. https://jsfiddle.net/rb9Lfvaq/. I don't see any issue. Can you tell what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: So, what is the issue? The hover seems to work fine. Everything else is fine aswell

Comment: _The problem is that the effect works when I hover the button_ that's how you have written the code, just `box-shadow` property is enough inside `:hover` section. No need to duplicate every properties in `:hover`!

Comment: This is what I see: https://i.imgur.com/r7SLrJD.jpg

Comment: Perhaps I should post the full code but I dont know if I should do this over stackoverflow?

Comment: Post the amount of code necessary to reproductive the problem.

Comment: Maybe You have style, that override Your .button4e styling? Inspect element (button) in developer tools of Your browser.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.styledButton {
    font-family: Arial;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    color: black;
    background-color: grey;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.styledButton:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
.styledButton:active {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<button class = "styledButton">Click Me!</button>
```

This should help. Any click animations I have trouble with.